# I am running Unity 3D without nVidia driver in Ubuntu 11.10!

Tags: unity, nvidia

you will perhaps amaze as I was but I am running Unity 3D in ubuntu 11.10 without nVidia driver and I hereby uploading the screen shot to prove this.

So my question is that will I even need to install the nVidia driver? And what is running to run this Unity 3D??
Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out ;)

[Nouveau: Accelerated Open Source driver for nVidia cards](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/)

I believe you are not experiencing no miracle here :)

Comment: That's mean that Nouveau comes default with 11.10! Wah!